# How to wget from list & multi-thread?

Tags: shell, command-line, wget

I've been using this to wget a large amount of URLs from a list I have stored in a text file:

```
wget -i websites.txt
```

However, it appears to me that downloads one file at a time and then moves on to the next.  I may be wrong about that, if so, please feel free to let me know.

But what if I wanted it to download 10 or 20 files simultaneously?  Is that possible to do with a simple wget command or is it going to require something more elaborate?

By the way, these are all extremely small files (~80kb) being downloaded. It just seems to take forever when downloading millions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **parallel** command:

```
parallel -a websites.txt --jobs 10 wget
```

with `-a` to read each line from the file, `--jobs` to say how many to
run in parallel, and `wget` will be suffixed by the next line from the file.

Comment: This limits the ability of wget to reuse connections. Consider `-n` to solve that problem.